# How does catboost choose a value for missing numeric values?

Tags: python, r, catboost

catboost sets missing values for numeric (float) fields to "the minimum value (less than all other values)" by default. What is the specific value that is chosen?

My concern is that the internal minimum value, determined from training data, is sufficiently low that the resulting model generalizes well to other data.

Example: in the training data, X1 has a minimum of A = 0. However, in the full dataset, on which we want to make predictions, X1 has a minimum of B = -100 (perhaps not known beforehand) If the internal encoding for missing values for X1, is, say, A-1 = -1, then values less than A that are not truly missing would be incorrectly considered to be in the missing group.

TL;DR: When should I encode missing values manually, based on what I know about my data, rather than relying on the internal numeric missing value encoding in catboost?

Comment: Often in these cases the "minimum" referred to is the machine integer or double minimum. While dangerous to just assume so, this would be my first guess. This is -(2**63 - 1) for integers and -1.79769e+308 for doubles. I can't access their site at the moment (Service not available) but this likely it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an actual value, they just send NAs to a given side of the split threshold. For that, you only need to know that a value is missing, no need to compare it against anything.